# Unable to understand the Crash Logs

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports

I have a view,which consists a `UIScrollView` on which subviews would added in `viewDidLoad` after adding all subviews & after the execution of all custom methods it goes to `viewWillappear`,after that it crashes with the following traces:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString CIImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7db5bb80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x04614946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0429da97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0461c5c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x045653e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x04564fae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x02b589f1 -[UIImageView _shouldDrawImage:] + 33
    6   UIKit                               0x02b58aa2 -[UIImageView _canDrawContent] + 164
    7   UIKit                               0x02a2f750 -[UIView(Internal) _shouldInheritScreenScaleAsContentScaleFactor] + 83
    8   UIKit                               0x02a2f7e9 -[UIView(Internal) _applyScreenScaleToContentScaleFactorIfNotSpecifiedByDeveloper] + 35
    9   UIKit                               0x02a2f56e -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1628
    10  UIKit                               0x02b5d762 -[UIImageView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 65
    11  UIKit                               0x02a2f23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
    12  UIKit                               0x02a423e1 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 65
    13  UIKit                               0x02a2f23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
    14  UIKit                               0x02a2f23f -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 813
    15  UIKit                               0x02a26517 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 154
    16  UIKit                               0x02a26475 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 458
    17  UIKit                               0x02a31f0d -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2018
    18  UIKit                               0x02a2486e -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    19  UIKit                               0x0299d0fa __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 1849
    20  UIKit                               0x02a2b7af +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 82
    21  UIKit                               0x0299c5a6 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1204
    22  UIKit                               0x02b2b64d -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3765
    23  UIKit                               0x02b38726 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    24  UIKit                               0x02b39372 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    25  UIKit                               0x02cad04c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    26  UIKit                               0x02a34dd1 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608
    27  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x042b3771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    28  QuartzCore                          0x0215928f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
    29  QuartzCore                          0x0214d115 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397
    30  QuartzCore                          0x0214cf70 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    31  QuartzCore                          0x020ab3c6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
    32  QuartzCore                          0x020ac78c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
    33  QuartzCore                          0x020ace58 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x045379de __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x04537920 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 400
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0452d35a __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0452cbcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0452c9fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x05e6b24f GSEventRunModal + 192
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x05e6b08c GSEventRun + 104
    41  UIKit                               0x029a98b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    42  POPCorn                             0x000e9472 main + 130
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x06193ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: are you using UIImageView in your code?

Comment: well I can't tell more without code, but look for an error there. From the stacktrace it looks like it's trying to rescale the image in the imageview and fails on that for some reason... I can't tell you what to look for.. But think what could be a problem with scaling..

Answer (score 0):

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString CIImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7db5bb80'`

You're accessing the CIImage property of an NSString (perhaps its id and you just accessed this property thinking that the id object was a UIImage). Search for `CIImage` in your class and make sure the object you're getting the property from is an actual `UIImage`.

Comment: here's the problem there is no CIImage in my whole project.

Comment: @AyanKhan read the stack trace, it tells which methods have been called to lead up to the crash. If you're using a storyboard, that might be the reason nothing in the stack trace makes sense.

Comment: i am not using storyboard and in the stack trace there is no clue.

Comment: @AyanKhan What custom methods do you use and do you pass any strings to id objects?

Comment: Sometimes-[__NSCFString CIImage]: replaced with -[__NSCFDictionay CIImage]: & sometimes -[__NSCFData CIImage]: in trace...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76224/discussion-between-schemetrical-and-ayan-khan).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out where the actual line of code that is causing i suggest creating an exception breakpoint. You can do this by going to the breakpoints tab and adding one for all exceptions. This along with the log you should see what you are passing an invalid argument to.